# UI Grid - Horizontal Scroll not working for large set of data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a very large set of data that will require horizontal scroll to fit on the page. Does UI Grid suppport horizontal scrolling for widths of data beyond the page?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/WcdQyUNm4UNxjdyX6UDh?p=preview

```
css:
.grid {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
}

js:
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.myData = [
    {
        "firstName": "Cox",
        "lastName": "Carney",
        "company": "Enormo",
        "employed": true
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Lorraine",
        "lastName": "Wise",
        "company": "Comveyer",
        "employed": false
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Waters",
        "company": "Fuelton",
        "employed": false
    }
];
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/E5CKlO4RlQhBL7boHBSF?p=preview)

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="yourGridOptions" class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

Inject `uiGridConstants` service.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'uiGridConstants', function($scope, uiGridConstants) {

  $scope.yourGridOptions = {
    enableHorizontalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.WHEN_NEEDED,
    enableVerticalScrollbar: uiGridConstants.scrollbars.WHEN_NEEDED,
    columnDefs: [{
      name: 'firstName',
     width:100

    }, {
      name: 'lastName',
     width:100

    }, {
      name: 'company',
      width:100

    }, {
      name: 'employed',
     width:100

    }],
    data: [{
      "firstName": "Cox",
      "lastName": "Carney",
      "company": "Enormo",
      "employed": true
    }, {
      "firstName": "Lorraine",
      "lastName": "Wise",
      "company": "Comveyer",
      "employed": false
    }, {
      "firstName": "Nancy",
      "lastName": "Waters",
      "company": "Fuelton",
      "employed": false
    }]
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Or you could just set `enableVerticalScrollbar: 2`. `0=off`, `1=on`, `2=when needed`. No need for importing. http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions